# Visual Studio 2013 debug extremely slow after install Sass related extension

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sass

I use MVC4 to develop on a website project and installed Mindscape workbench, Sass studio extension.

I also use bootstrap and Jquery script, not sure if this matters.

I usually edit scss file then save changed then view my change in browser while debugging, however, after working for a white, my editor becomes really slow, slow to click button, slow to type ( it takes couple seconds to move cursor ), almost slow at any interaction with keyboard and mouse. I have to restart my Visual Studio every time, it is really painful.

It is obviously something with SCSS extension to cause this slowness, because if I uninstall extension, this slowness is gone with it.

Has anyone also experienced this, and if you find solution of this, please kindly let me know, will really appreciate it!

Comment: This is still an issue. I have not found a solution either.
I am running VS2013 on Win7 64bit with latest Mindscape Web Workbench, Sass, VisualSVN and ReSharper; though disabling ReSharper had no perceivable effect. I am still looking for an answer and will update here if I find one.